# MVC 3 CodeFirst Share sql express database with all of my models

Tags: database, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, code-first

I am creating a data driven website with mvc3 using EF and code first.  I am trying to have all of my models share one database so that seperate roles can have access to common tables.  I am not sure weather to just use one db context because that seems like it might be the wrong way.  I do not want my models to create their own seperate databases. I want them to share but I cant seem to achieve this. Thank to any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instantiating multiple DbContexts will not cause you to have multiple databases unless you pass different connection strings into each one. If you have a single connection string, which will typically be kept in your web.config file, you can have many DbContexts, but they will all share the same database.

Answer (score 0):

You must deploy your database directly to SQL Server instead of using local file in `AppData` => your connection string mustn't use `AttachDBFile`.

Answer (score 0):

I was setting seperate DB contexts in all of my Models.  I know, what a noob mistake.  Thanks for the quick responses anyhow.  **[THIS](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/creating-a-more-complex-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application)** helped me figure it out and its really and amazaing resource for this stuff